# must be or would be?

Tags: modal-verbs, exam-questions

Here's a reading test that I did the other day:

> Dear Mr. Prosser,
> The information that you requested about changes to the hunting permit scheme has been enclosed. Please note that each permit must be filled out and applied for separately. When filling out your application, you must mark all answers clearly and with a black or blue pen. Please do not use cursive script, print only. Each application ______ enclosed in its own envelope and received before the applicable deadline. Received applications can take up to 5 weeks to process. Because of this, you must plan your submissions in a timely fashion to make sure that you receive your permit while the applicable season is still open. I hope that the information enclosed answers all of your questions. Take care and happy hunting.

I'm not sure why the answer says it should be "would be" in the blank, not "must be". In my opinion, must be is a more suitable answer since the whole mail is sort of telling the guy what to do in a relatively strong tone.

Comment: You are right, the missing text is "must be". **must** occurs three other times in the rest of the text: "would be" just would not make sense in this context.

Comment: **should be** would also fit.

Answer (score 1):

You are right - out of the options presented, **must be** is correct.  Here are some reasons you can provide if needed:

- The tone of the overall text is instructional and firm.  There are no other instances of "loose" language like *should, would, could,* etc
- Other instructions present in the text are similarly firm, using *must* and *only* to emphasize that the directions need to be followed as written.
- Using *would be* negates the instructional tone of the sentence, instead it sounds like an event that happens with or without the reader's agency.  It would no longer make sense with the context before and after this sentence.

Comment: What about using "shall" instead, would it make any sense?

Comment: @carloc I suppose you could use "shall be", but it sounds a bit archaic.  The intent of the sentence is most clear when using "must be".

Comment: Thank you much! I thought I remind something of the kind but it's been some 40 years since I was first tought English and suppose that archaic fits pretty well

Comment: @carloc You're welcome, and certainly use the words you like!  People still use "shall", sounds a bit posh/fancy/gentlemanly in an old-timey way if you know what I mean ;)  Think "shall we dance?" or "I shall be on my way".

Comment: Got it ;) Just consider that that I was so brainwashed by my teacher that even now it takes some effort to hold a "I beg your pardon" when I don't get someone, even a friend.